# how do I get only the time in models

Tags: python, django

How do I format datetime to give me only the time in my model

Answer (score 7):

If you've got a `datetime` object in your template called `foo`, use:

```
{{ foo|time:"H:i" }}
```

Look at the `time` filter [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#time). You're not limited to `"H:i"`, there are lots of options around for formatting `datetime` objects.

If for some reason you're wanting to do this directly in your model (which is *probably* not where it belongs), then use `datetime`'s `strftime` - take a look at the relevant [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-behavior).

For example, again assuming a `datetime` object called `foo`:

```
hour = foo.strftime("%H:%M")
```